# Шифровка и дешифровка фото при вызове django-модели

Tags: python, django, изображения, криптография

У меня есть:

```
class ChatAttachment(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media', name='qwe')
```

Как можно зашифровать изображение чтобы его нельзя было посмотреть через фс? Расшифровываться изображение будет при обращении к модели.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077109/how-can-i-create-an-encrypted-django-field-that-converts-data-when-its-retrieve

Comment: @Victor это больше подходит для шифрования строки, на весь файл это не особо применимо

Comment: Вообще с ImageField все довольно сложно. Как вариант, можно унаследоваться от `ImageField` и переопределить метод `pre_save`

Comment: Но если файл будет зашифрован, вы его просто так в img уже не покажете. Так что...